# cannot find route with name on iron router

Tags: meteor, coffeescript

I'm getting no route named view form although i have it defined correctly.

```
 Router.route '/form/:_id', (->
  @render 'viewForm', data: ->
    console.log 'id' + @params._id
    forms.findOne _id: @params._id
  return
),
  name: 'forms.show'
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
```

I redirect programmaticaly using this :

```
 Router.go('forms.show', {_id: id}, {query: 'q=s', hash: 'hashFrag'});
```

on console my routes are not even listed using :

```
Router.routes
```

is there an issue with name attribute ?

Comment: Maybe try removing dot from name

Answer (score 1):

The name attribute looks fine, does removing the extra parentheses fix the problem?

So the route function would instead be:

```
Router.route '/form/:_id', ->
  @render 'viewForm', data: ->
    console.log 'id' + @params._id
    forms.findOne _id: @params._id
  return
,
  name: 'forms.show'
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
```

Answer (score 0):

here is how i solved the problem:

```
  Router.route '/form/:_id',
  name: 'forms'
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
  action: ->
    @render 'viewForm', data: ->
      console.log 'id' + @params._id
      forms.findOne _id: @params._id
    return
```